# How to: scp over Jumphost, each with privatekeys

Tags: ssh, scp, public-key, ssh-tunnel

I want to have an scp command over a Jumphost to the targetserver. Both, the Jumphost and the targetserver, require an key for the login.

If there would be no key required, I think this command would work:

```
scp -o ProxyJump=usernameJumpserver@ipJumpserver filename usernameTargetserver@ipTargetserver:/path/filename
```

So, including a key, I get to this command:

```
scp -i /pathOnMyClient/key -o ProxyJump=usernameJumpserver@ipJumpserver filename usernameTargetserver@ipTargetserver:/path/filename
```

Then I get the error "usernameTargetServer@ipTargetserver: Permission denied (publickey)."

I can't add the (probably?) required -i /pathJumpserver/key to it. How does it work?

Answer (score 6):

So we have:

- LocalHost
- JumpHost
- DestinationHost

On LocalHost, in ~/.ssh/config add:

```
Host JumpHost
    User JumpHostUser
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    # other optional settings:
    # Port 2222
    # HostName 192.168.0.1    
Host DestinationHost
    User DestinationHostUser
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_jumphost
```

And you can use what @StefanKaerst suggested:

```
scp -o ProxyJump=JumpHost DestinationHost:/file /LocalFile
scp -o ProxyJump=JumpHost /Localile DestinationHost:/File
```

I have it aliased as

```
scpj='scp -o ProxyJump=JumpHost'
```

So I only type:

```
scpj DestinationHost:/file /LocalFile
```

You need to have all the keys in place though, both from local to jump, from jump to destination and from local to destination.

Comment: You can also add to your `~/.ssh/config` file in the DestinationHost section: `ProxyCommand ssh -qW %h:%p JumpHostUser@JumpHost` and then you don't need the alias. Just run `scp DestinationHost:/file /LocalFile`. You can also add port forwarding, if needed: `LocalForward 8080 localhost:8080`.

Comment: Agree with noname, also for Windows Jump host, when using user with admin grants it is needed to define `IdentityFile C:\ProgramData\ssh\ssh_host_ecdsa_key` (suitable key located in sshd home instead of user's home)

Answer (score 5):

as you cannot enter the password of your ssh key at the jumphost I suggest to load your key into your local ssh-agent and then use one of:

```
> scp -o ProxyJump=user@jump.host localfile user@target.host:

> scp -o ProxyJump=user@jump.host user@target.host:file localdir
```

this works for me!

HTH
Stefan K.

Answer (score 3):

I could not get this working with ProxyJump, so I fell back to the more verbose ProxyCommand instead.  This works for me for copying from A to C through B:

```
scp -i <path on A to key for C> \
    -oProxyCommand="ssh -i <path on A to key for B> -W %h:%p <user>@B" \
    /path/to/my/file <user>@C:~/
```

Comment: Had  remove the `${}` around `${myFile}`, then it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Right, that was meant to represent a variable you had set with the file path.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced ssh from windows, not much fun at all.
I've found this working.
Create a `C:\Users\u.username\.ssh\config` file like:

```
Host jumphost.server
  HostName jumphost.server
  User u.username
  ForwardAgent yes
  IdentityFile C:\Users\u.username\.ssh\id_rsa
 
Host * !jumphost.server
  ProxyCommand ssh.exe u.username@jumphost.server -W %h:%p
  IdentityFile C:\Users\u.username\.ssh\id_rsa
```

(replace your data for jumphost.server, as well as your username and path to ssh private key)

Then scp from final `target.server` is working that way (from powershell):

```
scp -F .\.ssh\config u.username@target.server:/path/to/file C:\Users\u.username\
```

or from local windows to target linux:

```
scp -F .\.ssh\config C:\Users\u.username\file u.username@target.server:/path/to/file
```

The flag `-F` is loading predefined config.

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me:

```
scp -o ProxyJump=USER_NAME@35.1.2.3 local-File.txt 10.1.2.3:~/
```